# Cómo cambiar el contexto de una función anónima autoejecutable?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo una función auto ejecutable, como puedo cambiarle el contexto ? ya que las funciones anónimas autoejecutables crean un scope aislado, pero como podría cambiarselo con call o apply ? por que lo intenté y no me funcionó, aquí el código:

```js
(function(w,d){
 function A(){
   this.go = () => {alert(14);};
 }

}).call(window, window,document); 

var obj = new A().go();
```

Comment: intento comprender pero no entiendo

Comment: Para referenciar al contexto definido por el método `call`  se emplea la palabra clave `this` , En su ejemplo sería de la siguiente forma , `this.A = function(){ ... }`

Comment: me refiero que el contexto de esta función queda aislado de window, y lo que quiero es que NO quede aislado, sino cambiarle su contexto a el de window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El hecho de que el contexto de la funcion anonima sea `Window`, no quiere decir que todo lo definido dentro ese ambito se agregara al objeto del contexto.

Para lograr lo que quieres, tienes que especificarle el origen del objeto al cual se agregara la funcion utilizando `this`, que representa window y a su vez el contexto:

```js
(function(w,d){
 this.A = function(){
   this.go = () => {alert(14);};
 }

}).call(window, window,document); 

var obj = new A().go();
```

---

Segun tu ejemplo, si le aplico el contexto al objeto impresora, este deberia de agregar el metodo `obtenerNivelTinta()` una vez se haya ejecutado la funcion anomina:

```js
var impresora = { 
 imprimir: function() { 
 alert("imprimiendo") 
 }
};
(function(){
function obtenerNivelTinta(){ 
 alert("bajo") 
}
}).call(impresora)

impresora.obtenerNivelTinta();
```

Pero como es de esperar no se le define ninguna funcion al objeto porque no estas especificandole el origen de a donde le *agregara* la funcion.

Ahora intentemos especificarle el origen de la funcion con this veras como si aparece:

```js
var impresora = { 
 imprimir: function() { 
alert("imprimiendo") 
 }
};
(function(){
this.obtenerNivelTinta = function(){ 
 alert("bajo") 
}
}).call(impresora)

impresora.obtenerNivelTinta();
```

Ahora si funciona como deberia porque ya sabe donde esta su origen y donde buscar la funcion para ejecutar.